# JerseyTest field becomes NULL in resource

Tags: java, jersey

For some strange reason a field of my entity has been changed to NULL in my resource.

**User Entity**
The User entity contains: userName, firstName, lastName, email. The JerseyTest instantiates a new User object:

```
newUser = new User();
    newUser.setEmail(getEmail());
    newUser.setFirstName("Erwin");
    newUser.setLastName("Eberhard");
    newUser.setUserName("abc");
```

**Send entity in test**
Before sending the data, the log in the test tells me:

```
[main] INFO feature.AccountStepDefinition - Erwin Eberhard erwin  
      erwineberhard@gmail.com
```

Everthing seems to be OK, so the test sends the data to the resource:

```
logger.info(newUser.toString());
responseUser = target("auth/register").request().post(Entity.json(newUser), User.class);
```

**AccountResource**
The AccountResource retrieves the user, and the log tells us:

```
[qtp1533672820-20] INFO nl.bolt.ffinschrijven.controllers.AccountsController   
- Erwin Eberhard null erwineberhard@gmail.com
```

For some reason the username has been changed in NULL.

**Method in AccountResource**

```
@POST
@Path("/register")
@ApiOperation(value = "Register user.", notes = "After registration a JWT token has been added as header value.")
@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "", response = User.class, responseHeaders = @ResponseHeader(name = "X-FFI-AUTH", description = "Token generated after authentication", response = String.class) )
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response callback(User user) {

        logger.info(user.toString());

        ServiceResult serviceResult = accountService.register(user);
        if (serviceResult.serviceState == ServiceState.success) {
            String jwt = "Bearer " + JwtHelper.createJWT(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), ApiConfiguration.issuer,
                    user.getEmail(), Long.valueOf(ApiConfiguration.token_ttl));
            return Response.status(201).entity(serviceResult.content).header("Authorization", jwt).build();
        }

        if (serviceResult.serviceState == ServiceState.invalid) {
            return Response.status(400).entity(serviceResult.responseMessages.toString()).build();
        }

        return Response.status(500).build();
}
```

**Postman**
When I send the data with POSTMAN, there is no problem:

*Headers*

Content-Type application/json

*Raw content*

```
{
"firstName": "Erwin",
"lastName" : "Eberhard",
"email" : "erwin@gmail.com",
"userName": "erwineberhard" 
}
```

How to get the beloved 201 with my JerseyTest?

**UPDATE 1**

**User.class**

The User class extends from a generic User class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User extends GenericUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Eventcomponent> eventcomponents =   
new ArrayList<Eventcomponent>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.getFirstName() + " " +  this.getLastName() + " " +     this.getUserName() 
    +  " " + this.getEmail();
}
}
```

**GenericUser.class**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class GenericUser implements IEmail{

@NotNull(message="Gebruikersnaam niet meegegeven.")
@Column(name="userName", nullable = false)
protected String userName;
@NotNull(message="Email niet meegegeven.")
@Column(name="email", nullable = false)
protected String email;
@NotNull(message="Voornaam niet meegegeven.")
@Column(name="firstName", nullable = false)
protected String firstName;
@NotNull(message="Achternaam niet meegegeven.")
@Column(name="lastName", nullable = false)
protected String lastName;
@Column(name="locked", nullable = false)
protected Boolean locked;

protected String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public Boolean getLocked() {
    return locked;
}
public void setLocked(Boolean locked) {
    this.locked = locked;
}  
}
```

Comment: 1) Show the User class. 2) When will the `callback` method ever result in a `User` response? Why are you doing `.post(Entity.json(newUser), User.class)`?

Comment: @peeskillet 1) See my update 2) I use this tool: [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). Sending raw json results in a User, for example: `{"email":"erwin2@gmail.com","firstName":"Erwin","lastName":"Eberhard","locked":false,"id":21}` 3) I've changed `.post...` to `post(Entity.json(newUser))`, I thought that adding the User.class was required for reading the response.

Comment: 2) The second argument to the `post` method says  that the response should be deserialized to a `User`. But looking at the resource method, it doesn't look like a `User` will ever be returned. I may be wrong. Instead, just use one argument for the `post` method, and it will return a `Response`. From the `Response` you can at least check things like the status code. and you can deserialize the response entity with `TheType message = response.readEntity(TheType.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `protected getUserName()` is the problem. The serializer can't find the `userName` property when serializing, so there is no field in the JSON of that property name, when it goes out. When the server gets the JSON there is no `"userName"` field, so it stays null in the server side object. To fix it, just make the method `public`.

Comment: You did it again! Thank you!!